# Write Heart Symbol in pdf using itext java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Trying to write heart symbol in pdf through java code . 
This is my input to pdf : ❤️❤️❤️

But pdf generated is empty without anything written.
Using itext to write to pdf.
The Font used is tradegothic_lt_boldcondtwenty.ttf

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A6);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
        document.open();

        PdfLayer nested = new PdfLayer("Layer 1", writer);
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.beginLayer(nested);
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);

        Font font = getFont();
        Phrase para1 = new Phrase("❤️❤️❤️",font);

        ct.setSimpleColumn(para1,38,0,260,138,15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        ct.go();

        cb.endLayer();

        document.close();
        file.close();

private Font getFont() { 

    final String methodName = "generatePDF";
    LOGGER.entering(CLASSNAME, methodName);

    Font font = null;
    try {

            String filename = tradegothic_lt_boldcondtwenty.ttf;
            FontFactory.register(filename, filename);
            font = FontFactory.getFont(filename, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED,11.8f);

    } catch(Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.logp(Level.SEVERE, CLASSNAME, methodName, "Exception Occurred while fetching the Trade Gothic font." + exception);
        font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD,11.8f);
    }
    return font;
}
```

Phrase para1 has the heart correctly. But not able to see in pdf

Comment: You use `BaseFont.CP1252` as encoding for your font. This encoding (which actually makes iText use **WinAnsiEncoding**) does not include a heart character. Use an appropriate encoding instead.

Comment: Can i try adding the heart symbol to the font file . Will that help ?

Comment: *"Can i try adding the heart symbol to the font file"* - I hoped you had at least checked beforehand that the symbol is present in your font. Obviously you need a font with a heart symbol to start with. And then you'll need an encoding including this symbol.